# Sharepoint 2013 JSLink

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, jslink

I'm able to make changes(like background color for specific item) in listview webpart using JSLink.

My query - When I change the view from 'Current View' to Other 'Custom View' in ListView Webpart. It takes me to customview.aspx page and I don't see the background color changes appear in the listitem.

FYI: js file located in style library.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page representing the other view ( customview.aspx in your case) is different from the page where JSLink is working for you. In this new page, you need to edit the web part to and include the JSLink reference just like it has been done for the other page.